# Summing the amount of a specific letter within a row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have any code for this because I have no idea how to do it but what I'm trying to do is find how many letters are within a specific row and have that number put into a different cell in the same row.

Maybe this will help explain, first thing I do is take a string of letters and break it down so that each is put into its own cell from there I need to find how many times a letter, eg. "A", occurs and have it put that number into a cell of its own.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That does what I need it to but when I put it into a macro it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method, applied to row 4:

[image]

**Explanation**

- Total number of characters in a row (eg for row 4):  `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(4:4))`
- Total number of *NOT* "a" characters in that row: `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(4:4,"a","")))`
- Total number of *NOT* "A" characters in that row: `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(4:4,"A","")))`
- Number of "a" + "A" characters: `2*SUMPRODUCT(LEN(4:4)) - SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(4:4,"a",""))) -SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(4:4,"A","")))`

It is necessary to subtract both "A" and "a" because `SUBSTITUTE` is case-sensitive. If we need to count case-sensitive letters (eg `a`) then the formula is simpler:

`SUMPRODUCT(LEN(4:4)) - SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(4:4,"a","")))`

The only caveat is that this formula cannot be placed on row 4, because a circular reference will occur.

**EDIT**

Uuuups, just noticed it should be `VBA`:

```
Option Explicit

Function noOfChars(myChar As String, lRow As Long) As Long
  ' Needs extra error handling, better to return a Variant 
  Dim sChars As String, vChar As Variant
  With Application
    vChar = .Transpose(.Transpose(Range(lRow & ":" & lRow).Value2))
  End With

  sChars = Join(vChar) ' <-- Needs error handling
  noOfChars = Len(sChars) - Len(Replace(sChars, myChar, vbNullString, _ 
     compare:=vbTextCompare)) ' <-- Needs error handling

End Function
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sheets("Peaks Net Charge Calc").Range("B1") =  "=COUNTIF(G1:CZ1,"A")"
That's what I'm trying to use in VBA but it keep giving me an out of range error. I assume it needs quotes somewhere but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try `Sheets("Peaks Net Charge Calc").Range("B1") = [COUNTIF(G1:CZ1,"A")]`. By the way, this will not count all the `A`s that you have in that range.. It counts Cell strings, not characters within a cell string..

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the error "Item with specified name wasn't found," any idea what that means?

Comment: Wow, I feel really smart now. I forgot to change it after copying it from some previous code. Thanks!

Comment: lol, your welcome! Have a look at [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/avoiding-excel-vba-errors-caused-by-changing-worksheet-names/), it will help next time!